# Python: Binary to image Conversion

Tags: python, image-processing, binaryfiles, binary-data, image-conversion

I have a binary file which contains an image with header.

The details are as follows.

- The first `1024 bytes` contain header Then `32 bytes` of header for each line
- Then `4608 bytes` constitute one line of image for **next** `5000 lines`.

So this would become a `4608x5000 pixel image` along with headers.

How should I read the **binary file** and how should I form and work with image?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If it is common format, try PIL

Answer (score 2):

You need to open the file (using binary mode if the code will run on Windows) then use the `read(size)` method to extract bytes.  If the image format is described in bytes, then you just pull apart the data as required.

Alternatively, if you need to convert values to integers etc, then Python has a [struct module](http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html) that can be used to unpack binary data (so you would read the data as above, but use struct to convert to integers etc).